# Filtering of Array using filter() works fine, but doesn't change in frontend

Tags: angular, angular5, angular7, angular8, angular9

component.ts

```
searchVideo = (search: string) => {
        this.query = search;
        if(this.videos.length == 0){
          this.filteredData = [];
        }
        if(!this.query){
          this.filteredData = this.videos;
        }
        const args = this.query.toLowerCase();
        this.filteredData = this.videos.filter((data: any) => {
          return JSON.stringify(data).toLowerCase().includes(args);
        });
        console.log(this.filteredData);
      }
```

component.html

```
<app-search-bar (sender)="searchVideo($event)"></app-search-bar>
...
<p>{{filteredData}}</p>
```

Frontend Output:
[image]

Console Output:

[image]

After filtering, data shown in console is absolutely correct which I want but while printed in frontend data remain same.

As you can see in console initially array size is 12, on input in input field, array filter itself to size 7 which is correct but on frontend array remain as it is which is 12

Comment: I think you need to call this function again in ngonit() or ngonchange()

Comment: can you please put the detectChanges() method where you're print console.log

Comment: @AmanGojariya, can you please ellaborate?

Comment: @SouvikPal You just need to add this.cdr.detectChanges();

Comment: add cdr: ChangeDetectionRef in constructor

Answer (score 1):

I have prepared a code sample that shows the usage of `filter` and it behaves as expected (similar to how you have used it).

But i think your issue is that you are trying to show an array of objects in your template which is behaving as expected. You should instead show the properties of your objects (or in general change the way you visualize your objects).

**Here is the code sample that shows the usage of `filter` and your issue and a possible solution:** [Code demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-7szcdb?file=src/app/app.component.html)